# Google Sheet Sparkline for every nth column

Tags: google-sheets, sparklines

I would like to add a Sparkline to a sheet showing the evolution of a value.

My table looks like this

| value #1 | diff former value | value #2 | diff former value | value #3 | diff former value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sparkline here |  | Sparkline here |  | Sparkline here |  |
| 10 | 0 | 8 | -2 | 9 | 1 |

My naive guess for the "Sparkline here" cell was (e.g. for C2)

```
    =SPARKLINE($A3:c3)
```

and for instance for E2

```
    =SPARKLINE($A3:e2)
```

unfortunately this takes the 0 (B3) and -2 (D2) into account.

Question: How can I create a sparkline that would only take every second value into account, i.e. 10, 8, 9.
Best if this could be done without adding a helper row/column somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=sparkline(filter(A3:F3, isodd(column(A3:F3))))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=sparkline(filter(A3:F3; isodd(column(A3:F3))))
```

This will include only the 'odd' columns in the specified range.